# is it possible to increate maximum page size for issues endpoint?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

initially I tried to sort issues at front-end i.e. bootstrap table but in vain, now I tried to do it at back-end, but maximum page size is 200 for issues endpoint, and we have 200+ issues need to be sorted, can it be changed and how?
Error: {"message":"Request failed with status code 400","response":{"errors":[{"title":"Invalid page value","detail":"Limit exceeds maximum page size of 200.","code":"118","status":"400"}]}}

Comment: with current design of Issue API, one page can only be max with 200 items. you can specify it with less, but not more. For any collection type of items (such as Issue, Documents, RFI etc), you must implement pagination extraction if you want to get all items, i.e. extract page by page. e.g. after getting first page (200 items), build a next call <issue API base url> ? offset=200&limit=200, then it will extract the next 200 items

Comment: if you want to get all items with easy way, you can use Data Connector or its API https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/overview/field-guide/data-connector/

Comment: ic, thanks Xiaodong, i remembered that you mentioned that your github sample "bim360-admin.dashboard" did extract all info at once, which method did you use? exact pages or data connector? which way is better? well, I haven't explore that sample in depth yet.

Comment: that sample extracts data by pagination. I have also sample that uses Data Connector API https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360-data.connector.dashboard. if you want to have all in a batch, Data Connector is the best choice

Comment: great! i managed to make it work using pagination, i'll try Data Connector API later, thanks again Xiaodong